# What is DNS for your domain in Salesforce

Tags: email, mydomain, dkim

I am creating DKIM Key in Salesforce. But to activate it saying "Before activating this key, add the CNAME and Alternate CNAME records in the DNS for your domain."

I don't understand how to find the DNS for my domain.

Could anyone please help me.

Thank you

Comment: We can't help you with this process. You need to contact your DNS provider (e.g. GoDaddy). If you're not sure, you can also do a WHOIS lookup, which may provide more information about how to contact the DNS provider.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox